# The term 'nmake' is not recognized

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017, nmake

I do something wrong but I do not know what. I have a PowerShell script, where I have a variable like this:

```
$VCVARSALLBAT = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"
```

Now, in this script I want to call this `vcvarsall.bat` doing this:

```
& "$($VCVARSALLBAT)" x86_amd64
```

From the output I see, it ran. After calling `vcvarsall.bat`, I call `nmake`.

I.e. my script looks like this:

```
$VCVARSALLBAT = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"
& "$($VCVARSALLBAT)" x86_amd64
nmake
```

I get this error message:

```
nmake : The term 'nmake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At ...:214 char:1
+ nmake
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nmake:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The odd thing is this: When I go into normal command line of Windows and calling the following statements, I can call `nmake` without errors:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64
nmake
```

Comment: Are you running x64 PowerShell or x86? My guess is that your are running 64 bit when you want to be running 32bit.

Answer (score 3):

If `nmake` is a program, try `nmake.exe`. `nmake.exe` needs to be in your path for this to work. If it isn't, you can (a) specifying the full path to the executable (b) or add the executable to your path. You can see if the executable is in your path by calling `where.exe nmake` from a Powershell or CMD prompt.

**ADDED TO ANSWER**

Here's what `where.exe` does...

[image]

If you find something in CMD but not Powershell, I'd verify your paths match:

[image]

If the given program is in your path, `where.exe` will find it, even in Powershell.

[image]

To the original post, you were getting the standard, "I can't find your command." exception from Powershell:

[image]

If you really want to test whether you can call the exe from Powershell, call it explicitly:

`'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\Hostx86\x86\nmake.exe'`

If that works and you want to call it by program name, double check your path.

Comment: I tried `nmake.exe`, but I still get the same error. Calling `& "$($VCVARSALLBAT)" x86_amd64` in my case in Powershell should set the path to `nmake.exe`, but Powershell does not recignize it.

Comment: Did you use ```where.exe``` to see if ```nmake.exe``` is in your path?

Comment: In command line I get this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\Hostx86\x86\nmake.exe`. In Powershell nothing.

Comment: If the purpose of the batch file is to populate environment variables, then you can't just run it from PowerShell. (This is because PowerShell executes the script using `cmd.exe`, but when `cmd.exe` terminates, the variables are disposed.) See answer in duplicate link for a PowerShell function that works around this.

Comment: Visual Studio comes with several batch files of this type. You can't execute them directly in PowerShell and have the environment variables persist. The function I wrote (link in comment on question) works around this limitation.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Good information, but unfortunately doesn't help with the stated problem. The documented means for working with the VS tools is to run the batch files to set the needed environment variables (hence my answer in the duplicate link).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, there is no dispute about the quality of your answer. The update qualifies concerns around calling of executable in Powershell and the use of where.exe. To be blunt, no one is disputing that setting variables through a DOS batch script makes those values available through their containing Powershell session.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding. Simply adding the `nmake.exe` directory to the `Path` variable isn't going to help, because the VS batch scripts set a group of other related environment variables that all have to be set for command-line builds to work.